# How to resolve the dependency and compile the Junit test classes using Gradle Bulid Tool

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to Gradle, currently i added a small java projects and executed well.

Correct me if my understanding since java is available we are able to complie the java project and executed well.

To test i have wirtten a test class with help of junit, but I couldn't not compile and not able to pull the dependency from the maven there was an issue.

When I checked with stacktrace option I find that the issue is **java.net.UnknownHostException: repo1.maven.org** when i tried to access through google it says the Directory browsing is disabled, perhaps it may only for pulling dependency.

Below I have given the steps followed along with the error details.

Kindly help me how to resolve or please suggest how to proceed or correct me if my understanding is wrong.

**Compilation of Java Class**

[image]

**Compilation of Junit without stacktrace**

[image]

**Compilation of Junit with Stack Trace**

```
D:\Public\NetbeansApp\ShopCart>gradle -s build
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testCompile'.
> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
  Required by:
      :ShopCart:unspecified
   > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testCompile'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(SelfResol
vingDependencyResolver.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(Erro
rHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:180)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:444)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:205)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveCont
ext.java:191)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75
)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveCont
ext.java:182)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75
)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext$FileTreeConverter.convertInto(DefaultFileCollectionResolveCont
ext.java:182)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.doResolve(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.resolveAsFileTrees(DefaultFileCollectionResolveContext.java:75
)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection$1.resolve(CompositeFileCollection.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileCollection.java:143)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.getSourceCollections(CompositeFileTree.java:30)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.getFiles(CompositeFileCollection.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.TaskUpToDateState.<init>(TaskUpToDateState.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactState
Repository.java:126)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStat
eRepository.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Required by:
    :ShopCart:unspecified
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:81
)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainAdapter.resolve(RepositoryChainAdapter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBu
ilder.java:577)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.getMetaData(DependencyGra
phBuilder.java:587)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(Depend
encyGraphBuilder.java:272)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(Depende
ncyGraphBuilder.java:246)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:156)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveDependencyGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:
94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:122)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:88)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:187)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:40)

        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDep
endencyResolver.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:4
7)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:250)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:442)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12
.pom'.
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:
72)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResou
rceArtifactResolver.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveMetaDataArtifact(DefaultExternalReso
urceArtifactResolver.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:16
2)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:141)

        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:82)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalRe
sourceResolver.java:391)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess$2.run(Ca
cheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:237)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:308)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:114)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheFactory.java:179)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess.resolveC
omponentMetaData(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMe
taData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:284)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(BaseModuleComponentRep
ositoryAccess.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveComponentMetaD
ata(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.j
ava:114)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.j
ava:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:70
)
        ... 92 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo1.maven.org
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:278)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:118)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:111)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:87)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:78)
        ... 120 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.846 secs

D:\Public\NetbeansApp\ShopCart>
```

**App project structure with Test Class**

[image]

**Build script**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.
//
// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = ''
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.gradle.shopcart.ShopCartApp'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // You may define additional repositories, or even remove "mavenCentral()".
    // Read more about repositories here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories
}

dependencies {
    // TODO: Add dependencies here ...
    // You can read more about how to add dependency here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

}
```

**Error of Directory**

[image]

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy? Can you ping `repo1.maven.org`?

Comment: Yes i'm behind the proxy. Currently I tested from home system it's working fine

Answer (score 3):

As you commented you are trying to make it work behind a corporate proxy. You need to setup your Gradle properly, so it can load the dependencies with the proxy in mind. To do so you should follow the [Gradle User Guide section 20.2.](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html) `Accessing the web via a proxy`.

Often this doesn't work either because the corporate proxy is a *special* proxy which required a special authentication mechanism (NTLM). Therefore you should check out the [**Cntlm Authentication Proxy**](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html). Cntlm is a local HTTP Proxy which is able to authentication against your corporate proxy and forward the traffic from the local proxy to corporate proxy.

Another solutions would be a own Maven Repository Server/Proxy/Cache like [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/#os-arti) or [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus).

Answer (score 1):

It indeed looks like your machine fail to download junit from maven. This assumption is based on the error you provided above:

```
`> Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'`.
```

I checked and this file does exists so you should check whether your machine has access to it. If it is indeed not accessible from yours then you can follow the steps in Gradle doc [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) to set up a proxy for accessing the web.

Comment: Yes I'm behind the proxy. Currently I tested from home system the  dependency is working fine but I'm facing another issue with compilation problem. Let me check with gradle properties.