# Unknown Peer Not Authenticated Error Android Studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, junit

I import my project from one computer to another and I got this error:

```
Gradle 'Project_name' project refresh failed
Error:Cause: peer not authenticated
```

I have tried many solutions available here, but they did not work.

> [Android Studio Gradle build failed. Error:Cause: peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734738/android-studio-gradle-build-failed-errorcause-peer-not-authenticated)
>
> [How to resolve the dependency and compile the Junit test classes using Gradle Bulid Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536278/how-to-resolve-the-dependency-and-compile-the-junit-test-classes-using-gradle-bu)
>
> [Android Studio / Intellij, Gradle Error:Cause: peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206040/android-studio-intellij-gradle-errorcause-peer-not-authenticated)
>
> [How to resolve the dependency and compile the Junit test classes using Gradle Bulid Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536278/how-to-resolve-the-dependency-and-compile-the-junit-test-classes-using-gradle-bu)

I have attached a log file with details. Please check it.

I don't know what the actual issue is. I got stuck from last 7 days. Can any expert help me to get rid of this issue. This platform is my last hope. Please please help me to resolve my issue.